# could not broadcast input array from shape (27839,1) into shape (27839)

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I'm building a chain classifier for a multiclass problem that uses Keras binary Classifier model in a chain. I have 17 labels as classification target and shape of X_train is (111300,107) and y_train is (111300,17). After training, I got following Error in predict method;

```
        *could not broadcast input array from shape (27839,1) into shape (27839)*
```

My code is here:

```
def create_model():
  input_size=length_long_sentence
  embedding_size=128
  lstm_size=64
  output_size=len(unique_tag_set)
    #----------------------------Model--------------------------------
  current_input=Input(shape=(input_size,)) 
  emb_current = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=input_size)(current_input)
  out_current=Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_size))(emb_current )
  #out_current = Reshape((1,2*lstm_size))(out_current)
  output = Dense(units=1, activation=  'sigmoid')(out_current)
  #output = Dense(units=1, activation='softmax')(out_current)
  model = Model(inputs=current_input, outputs=output)
  #-------------------------------compile-------------
  model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1,batch_size=256, shuffle = True, verbose = 1,validation_split=0.2)
chain=ClassifierChain(model, order='random', random_state=42)
history=chain.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

the result for chain.classes_ is given below:

```
[array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([0, 1], dtype=uint8)]
```

then trying to predict on Test data:

```
Y_pred_chain = chain.predict(X_test)
```

The summary of the model is given below:
[image]

Full Trace of error is here:

```
109/109 [==============================] - 22s 202ms/step
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-34a25ad06cd4> in <module>()
----> 1 Y_pred_chain = chain.predict(X_test)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/multioutput.py in predict(self, X)
    523             else:
    524                 X_aug = np.hstack((X, previous_predictions))
--> 525             Y_pred_chain[:, chain_idx] = estimator.predict(X_aug)
    526 
    527         inv_order = np.empty_like(self.order_)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (27839,1) into shape (27839)
```

Can any one help about how to fix this error?

Comment: I would double check the shape of X_test.

Comment: shape of X_test is (27839, 107).

Comment: After training, could you print `chain.classes_` and write what it outputs?

Comment: I have added output for chain.classes_ in main post.

Comment: This is kind of a long shot but I had a similar issue that I solved by using `np.array(X_test)` as the input. I think it has something to do with whether or not the pointer for `X_test` actual "controls" the memory

Comment: np.array(X_test) raise the similar  error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Stage 1

Going by the model summary as posted in the question, I start with that the input size of `107` and the output size is `1` (binary classification task)

Lets break it into pieces and understand.

#### The Model architecture

```
input_size = 107    
# define the model
def create_model():
  global input_size
  embedding_size=128
  lstm_size=64
  output_size=1
  vocab_size = 100

  current_input=Input(shape=(input_size,)) 
  emb_current = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=input_size)(current_input)
  out_current=Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_size))(emb_current )
  output = Dense(units=output_size, activation=  'sigmoid')(out_current)
  model = Model(inputs=current_input, outputs=output)
  model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```

#### Some dummy data

```
X = np.random.randint(0,100,(111, 107))
y = np.random.randint(0,2,(111,1))  # NOTE: The y should have two dimensions
```

#### Lets test the keras model directly

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1, batch_size=8, shuffle = True, verbose = 1,validation_split=0.2)
model.fit(X, y)
y_hat = model.predict(X)
```

Output:

```
Train on 88 samples, validate on 23 samples
Epoch 1/1
88/88 [==============================] - 2s 21ms/step - loss: 0.6951 - accuracy: 0.4432 - val_loss: 0.6898 - val_accuracy: 0.5652
111/111 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
(111, 1)
```

Ta-da! it works

#### Now lets chain them and run

```
model=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, verbose=1,validation_split=0.2)
chain=ClassifierChain(model, order='random', random_state=42)
chain.fit(X, y)
print (chain.predict(X).shape)
```

oops! it trains but predictions fails as OP points out
Error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (111,1) into shape (111)
```

#### The problem

This error is because of the below line in sklearn

```
--> 525             Y_pred_chain[:, chain_idx] = estimator.predict(X_aug)
```

It is because classifier chain runs the estimators one at a time and saves each estimators predictions in `Y_pred_chain` at the estimators index (determined by the `order` parameter). It assumes that the estimators return the predictions in a 1D array. But keras models return output of shape `batch_size x output_size` which in out our case is `111 x 1`.

#### The solution

We need a way to reshape the predictions of shape `111 X 1` to `111` or in general `batch_size x 1` to `batch_size`. Lets bank on the concepts of OOPS and overload the predict method of `KerasClassifier`

```
class MyKerasClassifier(KerasClassifier):
  def __init__(self, **args):
    super().__init__(**args)

  def predict(self, X):
    return super().predict(X).reshape(len(X)) # Here we are flattening 2D array to 1D

model=MyKerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, verbose=1,validation_split=0.2)
chain=ClassifierChain(model, order='random', random_state=42)
chain.fit(X, y)
print (chain.predict(X).shape)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/1
88/88 [==============================] - 2s 19ms/step - loss: 0.6919 - accuracy: 0.5227 - val_loss: 0.6892 - val_accuracy: 0.5652
111/111 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step
(111, 1)
```

Ta-da! it works

## Stage 2

Lets look deeper into [ClassifierChain](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.ClassifierChain.html) class

> A multi-label model that arranges binary classifiers into a chain.
>
> Each model makes a prediction in the order specified by the chain
> using all of the available features provided to the model plus the
> predictions of models that are earlier in the chain.

So what we really need is a `y` of shape `111 X 17` so that the chain contains 17 estimators. Lets try it

#### The real ClassifierChain

```
y = np.random.randint(0,2,(111,17))
model=MyKerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, verbose=1,validation_split=0.2)
chain=ClassifierChain(model, order='random', random_state=42)
chain.fit(X, y)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_62 to have shape (107,) but got array with shape (108,)
```

It cannot train the model; the reason is pretty simple. The chain first trains the first estimator with `107` feature with works fine. Next the chain picks up the next estimator and then trains it with `107` features + the single output of the previous estimator (=108). But since our model has input size of `107` it will fail as so the error message. Each estimator will get `107` input features + the output of all the previous estimators.

#### The solution [hacky]

We need a way to change the `input_size` of the model as they are created from the `ClassifierChain`. There seem to be no callbacks or hooks into the `ClassifierChain`, so I have a hacky solution.

```
input_size = 107    

# define the model
def create_model():
  global input_size
  embedding_size=128
  lstm_size=64
  output_size=1
  vocab_size = 100

  current_input=Input(shape=(input_size,)) 
  emb_current = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=input_size)(current_input)
  out_current=Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_size))(emb_current )
  output = Dense(units=output_size, activation=  'sigmoid')(out_current)
  model = Model(inputs=current_input, outputs=output)
  model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

  input_size += 1 # <-- This does the magic
  return model

X = np.random.randint(0,100,(111, 107))
y = np.random.randint(0,2,(111,17))
model=MyKerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, verbose=1,validation_split=0.2)
chain=ClassifierChain(model, order='random', random_state=42)
chain.fit(X, y)
print (chain.predict(X).shape)
```

Output:

```
Train on 88 samples, validate on 23 samples
Epoch 1/1
88/88 [==============================] - 2s 22ms/step - loss: 0.6901 - accuracy: 0.6023 - val_loss: 0.7002 - val_accuracy: 0.4783
Train on 88 samples, validate on 23 samples
Epoch 1/1
88/88 [==============================] - 2s 22ms/step - loss: 0.6976 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.7070 - val_accuracy: 0.3913
Train on 88 samples, validate on 23 samples
Epoch 1/1
----------- [Output truncated] ----------------
111/111 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step
111/111 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step
(111, 17)
```

As expected it trains `17` estimators and `predict` method returns output of shape `111 x 17` each column corresponding to the predictions made by the corresponding estimator.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer. let me try it.

Comment: I solved the problem with input size by making it none, so it will not be fixed like in our case its 107.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It worked by customizing the keras classifier  and overloading the predict method. Thanks

Comment: customized kerasclassifier predict method worked on google colab notebook but when I tried to run it on server it gave me this error 'model object has no attribute,'predict_classes'. Any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

here a complete working example...

I solved using sequential model and softmax as the last activation

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from sklearn.multioutput import ClassifierChain

n_sample = 20
vocab_size = 33
input_size = 100

X = np.random.randint(0,vocab_size, (n_sample,input_size))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, (n_sample,17))

def create_model():
    
    global input_size
    embedding_size = 128
    lstm_size = 64
    
    model = Sequential([
        Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=input_size),
        Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_size)),
        Dense(units=2, activation=  'softmax')
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    input_size += 1
    
    return model

model = tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1, batch_size=256, 
                        shuffle = True, verbose = 1, validation_split=0.2)
chain = ClassifierChain(model, order='random', random_state=42)
chain.fit(X, y)

chain.predict_proba(X)
```

here the running code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aVjjh6VPmAyBddwU4ff2w9y_LmmC02W_?usp=sharing